# Understanding acync and await in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm learning async and await operation in c#. I couldn't understand the flow of execution when it handles multiple async operation. for eg: I have the below code in my c# application.

```
await repository.GetAsync(values); // execute for 10 sec                              
var result = repository.setAsync(data); // 20 sec
dataresult = await repository.GetAsync(result); //execute for 10 sec
```

I have three async calls here.

As per my understanding each call will have a callback and this will not wait for one action to complete.

So how I can ensure the action is complete?

**The repository.setAsync will execute before repository.GetAsync(values) complete its execution? or this will execute only after repository.GetAsync(values) execution completed?**

So what will be the order of execution?

1)

```
await repository.GetAsync(values); // started await method execution, since there is no callback it will not set and will start execute the next before complete this.                              
var result = repository.setAsync(data); // will execute for 20 sec. Once completed will go to previous thread and complete that.
```

2. 

```
await repository.GetAsync(values); // started await method execution, complete it and move to the next line.
var result = repository.setAsync(data); // will execute for 20 sec.
```

**When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task. When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes. But here, for asynchronous it waiting for the operation to finish. Why this contradiction?**

I want to return the dataresult only once the operation has been completed.
I feel this is contrary to fire and forget. Whether these two are same or different concepts?
As per the below link [reference](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)

> The await keyword does not block the thread until the task is
> complete.

But from the answers posted here, I understood this will pause the execution. which is true? Am I missed something?

Comment: Simply put: `await` is an "asynchronous wait", so the *method* will wait for it to complete, but the *thread* is not blocked. You may find my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As per my understanding each call will have a callback and this will not wait for one action to complete.

When you use `await`, the code will wait for the action to complete before moving on. This is the way you deal with data dependencies -- situations when a task needs results from a previous task to be available before it can start processing. The only action that is not awaited is `result`, so `GetAsync(result)` must take `Task<T>` as its parameter, where `T` is the type of whatever `SetAsync` method returns.

**Note**

If code following the `await` does not need to be executed on the UI thread you should call `ConfigureAwait(false)` upon the `Task` you are awaiting. Why is this best practice? Stephen Cleary provides an excellent [blog post on the topic of async/await deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that explains it.

It is also very likely that you are missing `await` on the second line and an assignment of `data` on the first line:

```
var data = await repository.GetAsync(values).ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = await repository.SetAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
dataresult = await repository.GetAsync(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

> So what is the concept of callback and fire and forget here?

If callback happens before the call of `await`, which is possible when you fire up a task, do something else, and then `await` that task, you get a chance to do more work in between "firing and forgetting" and getting the results back. The key here is that there must be no data dependency in the middle:

```
var dataTask = repository.GetAsyncOne(values); // Fire and forget
// Do something else in the middle
var result = await repository.SetAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
// If the task has completed, there will be no wait
var data = await dataTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The only action that is not awaited is result. Can you please elaborate this? I couldnt see any difference in code between this line and other. Please help

Comment: @TomCruise The middle line in your code says `var result = repository.setAsync(data);`, i.e. there's no `await`. Assuming that `setAsync` is an `async` method, its signature is `Task<SomeClass>`, so `result` is a task.

Comment: So async opeations with await will make the thread wait for the action to complete? so what is the concept of callback and fire and forget here?

Comment: If you use await when calling an async operation, there is no fire-and-forget. If you don't need the result of the async call immediately, you can call async method without await (fire and forget) and you can continue working with other operations. At the point when you require the result of the call then you use await which will cause the program to wait until the async call has completed and returned the result

Comment: Fine.its clear.  Await will have callback? or this is applicable only to sync calls?

Comment: When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task. When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes.But here , for asynchronous it waiting for the operation to finish. Why this contradiction?

Comment: What on earth is _"in a UI thread"_. This answer could have quoted one of the _many many articles_ about asyc/await and been better for it.

Comment: *So async opeations with await will make the thread wait for the action to complete?* - no, the thread can go on its merry way and do something else (assuming you are not blocking it higher up the call stack): the *rest of the method* has to wait. Think of it this way - if I'm waiting for the toaster, I can go off and do something else - but I can't butter the toast yet.

Comment: @Gusdor If you don't know what on Earth is in a UI thread, by all means ask a question, or use your favorite search engine. If you have specific recommendations as to improving the answer, please suggest an edit. This will save everybody a lot of time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I know what it a) means, and I also understand b) the intent. The problem is, A and B are different. This makes the statement _technically wrong_ - in this business, that is quite important. I'd hope someone with 450k rep would place value in the accuracy of an answer but I guess time is a factor when there are hundreds of duplicates to answer... I'll go ahead and suggest an edit.

Comment: Its quite confusing. Can anyone help me to understand whether asyncrhonous calls will behave like synchronous when using await.

Comment: @TomCruise `async` calls remain asynchronous. `await` will block the progress of the rest of the method until its `async` task returns (i.e. delivers its callback with the result). If, on the other hand, the result has been delivered before your method has reached the `await`, there would be no waiting at all. Moreover, although the method cannot continue past the `await`-ed call, its other `async` calls that have not been awaited can continue making progress. I know, this is very confusing, but this is a complex subject, so you don't want to oversimplify it to the point of being incorrect.

Comment: The repository.setAsync will execute before repository.GetAsync(values)? or this will execute only after repository.GetAsync(values)?

Comment: @TomCruise In your code `setAsync(data)` cannot **start** before `GetAsync(values)` is complete, because `GetAsync` is `await`-ed. If you don't need the results of `GetAsync` to be available before you start `setAsync`, but you want it to complete before you end your method, do this: `var task = repository.GetAsync(values); var result = repository.setAsync(data); dataresult = await repository.GetAsync(result); await task.ConfigureAwait(false);`